# INDEX is not returning a match when using a variable substring

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have compiled code with gfortran and AOCC flang compiler, but it fails for both, is there anything wrong I am doing?

```
  program find_sub_indx
        implicit none
    !decl
        character(len =30) :: main_string, sub_string
        integer ::  index_1 , index_2
        logical :: back
    !defn   
        main_string = "this is the main string"
        sub_string = "a"
        back = .false.

        index_1 = INDEX(main_string, sub_string, back)  !why does this not work 
        index_2 = INDEX("this is the main string","a", .false.) !this works why?
        print *, "index_1 is " , index_1, index_2
    end program find_sub_indx
```

Result expected:

```
index_1 is             14           14
```

Actual result:

```
index_1 is             0           14
```

Is there some standard reference for learning fortran, as I couldn't find the proper definition of intrinsic function used above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first attempt to use `index`

```
INDEX(main_string, sub_string, back)
```

the variables `main_string` and `sub_string` are both of length 30.  After the assignment

```
 sub_string = "a"
```

the variable `sub_string` has value starting with `a` *but has 29 trailing spaces* after that.

So, the function is evaluated like

```
INDEX(main_string, 'a                             ', back)
```

That substring is, of course, not found in `main_string` and the result is correctly `0`.

You can instead use

```
INDEX(main_string, TRIM(sub_string), back) !or
INDEX(main_string, sub_string(1:1), back)
```

or declare `sub_string` to be of length `1`.

The literal constant `"a"` in the second attempt has length 1 and does not have these trailing spaces.

Comment: Thanks,Is there some standard reference for learning fortran, as I couldn't find the proper definition of intrinsic function used above.

Comment: You can read the language standards (links found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fortran/info)), but your compiler's documentation is likely to provide such descriptions also.

Comment: @SameeranJoshi If you want a book I would recommend https://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/oso/9780198811893.001.0001/oso-9780198811893